# Pandas: reverse Liker survey answers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem:

I have a survey that contains a large number of answers to likert questions, like so:

```
id | Q1 | Q2 | Q3
1     5    3    1
2     3    4    1
3     2    3    1
```

The problem is that not all questions are asked in 'the same direction'. So a answer of '5' in Q1 would indicate a positive answer. But a 5 in Q2 would mean a strongly negative answer.

We are currently re-encoding all questions by hand (thus replacing all Q2 5's with 1's, etc)  but I was wondering if there is a quicker way to solve this.

I thought about dividing all answers by 5 and then subtracting 1, but that never gives me whole numbers. Math isn't really my strongpoint here, so I was wondering if someone here could help me out

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: All questions are asked on 1 to 5 scale. With 1 being negative and 5 being positive. (Ideally) but due to an error Q2 is encoding with 1 being positive and 5 being negative

Comment: Why not just subtract the to-be-reversed value from 6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can do it so:

```
df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].map({1:5, 2:4, 3:3, 4:2, 5:1})
```

Input:

```
   Q1  Q2  Q3
0   5   3   1
1   3   4   1
2   2   5   1
```

Output:

```
   Q1  Q2  Q3
0   5   3   1
1   3   2   1
2   2   1   1
```

Comment: @Jasper, if an answer solved your issue, please accept it to indicate it as such.

Comment: @IMCoins Thanks! mine was the first solution that came in my mind

Comment: I like this answer as this approach generalizes to switching to any other rating scheme.

Answer (score 5):

You can subtract `6` from column `Q2`, or use [`rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rsub.html) what subtract from right side:

```
print (df)
   Q1  Q2  Q3
0   5   3   1
1   3   4   1
2   2   5   1

df.Q2 = 6 - df.Q2
#same as
#df.Q2 = df.Q2.rsub(6)
```

If performance is important subtract by `numpy array`:

```
df.Q2 = 6 - df.Q2.values
```

Or:

```
df.Q2 = df.eval(' 6 - Q2')
```

Or:

```
import numexpr

x = df.Q2.values
df.Q2 = numexpr.evaluate('(6 - x)')
```

---

---

```
print (df)
   Q1  Q2  Q3
0   5   3   1
1   3   2   1
2   2   1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would personally do this.

Considering your example `data.csv`...

```
id,q1,q2,q3
1,5,3,1
2,3,4,1
3,2,3,1
```

My solution would do...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv')
print df
    id  q1  q2  q3
0   1   5   3   1
1   2   3   4   1
2   3   2   3   1

my_rates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df['q2'] = df['q2'].apply(lambda x:my_rates[-x])
print df
   id  q1  q2  q3
0   1   5   3   1
1   2   3   2   1
2   3   2   3   1
```

## Benchmark

With larger datasets, results change drastically.

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit

df = pd.read_csv('test_csv.csv')
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

def imcoins(df):
    my_rates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].apply(lambda x:my_rates[-x])
    return df

def joe(df):
    df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].map({1:5, 2:4, 3:3, 4:2, 5:1})
    return df

def jez(df):
    df.Q2 = 6 - df.Q2
    return df

def jez_2(df):
    df.Q2 = df.Q2.rsub(6)
    return df

def jez_3(df):
    df.Q2 = 6 - df.Q2.values
    return df

nb = 10000
t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt='imcoins(df)', setup='from __main__ import imcoins, df', number=nb)
t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt='joe(df)', setup='from __main__ import joe, df', number=nb)
t3 = timeit.timeit(stmt='jez(df)', setup='from __main__ import jez, df', number=nb)
t4 = timeit.timeit(stmt='jez_2(df)', setup='from __main__ import jez_2, df', number=nb)
t5 = timeit.timeit(stmt='jez_3(df)', setup='from __main__ import jez_3, df', number=nb)

print 'IMCoins : {}\njoe : {}\njezrael_1 : {}\njezrael_2 : {}\tjezrael_3 : {}'.format(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)

# Python 2.7
IMCoins : 3.85911526513
joe : 1.26151379163
jezrael_1 : 0.487986194544
jezrael_2 : 0.613230951967
jezrael_3 : 0.287318529541

# Python 3.6
IMCoins : 2.0433933256597467
joe : 1.3545644831475654
jezrael_1 : 0.482208606992109
jezrael_2 : 0.5195013265458606
jezrael_3 : 0.27176954323496627
```

Comment: Try add `df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)` for larger data.

Comment: @jezrael did it, results are very different with large datasets.

Comment: Yes, apply here is slow. And DataFrame have only 3k rows.

Comment: @jezrael Results are also different if using python 2.7 (as i did), or python 3.6 (updated version). However, your solution did not move, or very slightly.

Comment: I add new solution `df.Q2 = 6 - df.Q2.values` it should be faster

Comment: I'm not convinced that speed was ever an issue here.

Comment: @jezrael I updated using df.Q2.values, but I invite you to edit this post for further notes you would want to add :)

Comment: btw, do you use IDE spyder and anaconda?

Comment: @jezrael I have a slightly customed Sublime Text, anaconda for python36. I currently am hesitating to switch on either pycharm or spyder, but i still need to take actions. why's that ?

Comment: Because timings in spyder are really easy, only use `%timeit joe(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is general function that will work over any number of columns in a dataframe you may want to reverse code. Let's try it out with some sample data

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
         'A': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
         'B': [9, 2, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 7, 2, 8],
         'C': [2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 7, 8]
         }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Now the function that will reverse code the data in columns `A and B`

```
# columns to reverse code
vars = ['A', 'B']

# define function to reverse code data
def reverse_code(data):
    cols = data.columns
    max_value = data.max(axis=0)
    if set(vars) & set(cols):
         data.loc[:, vars] = (max_value + 1) - data.loc[:, vars]
    
    return data
    

print('\nreverse-coded \n', reverse_code(df1))

df1
   A  B  C
0  3  9  2
1  3  2  4
2  3  3  1
3  3  2  0
4  3  4  2
5  3  0  1
6  3  2  3
7  3  7  0
8  3  2  7
9  3  8  8

reverse-coded
   A   B  C
0  1   1  2
1  1   8  4
2  1   7  1
3  1   8  0
4  1   6  2
5  1  10  1
6  1   8  3
7  1   3  0
8  1   8  7
9  1   2  8
```